# joining 3 tables in laravel using DB with similar column names

Tags: laravel, join

I have three 3 tables in my database `user_projects`with columns

```
 project_id,
 user_id,
 role
```

`project_invitations` with columns

```
 project_id,
 email,
 role
```

and finally `users` 

`id,
email`

I want to join the three tables using the laravel query builder so that I can get

```
userid,  role,  email,          invited_user 
null    member  test@gmail.com          true
1       owner   test123@gmail.com       false
2       member  test12@gmail.com        true
```

So far I got the following data

```
[
    {
        "email":"test@sharklasers.com",
        "id":2,
        "role":"owner",
        "invitedEmail":"test@gmail.com",
        "invitedRole":"member"
    },
    {
        "email":"test@sharklasers.com",
        "id":2,
        "role":"owner",
        "invitedEmail":"safda@gmail.com",
        "invitedRole":"member"
    }
]
```

using the following query

```
DB::table('user_projects')
            ->join('users', 'user_projects.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('project_invitations', 'project_invitations.project_id','=','user_projects.project_id')
            ->where('user_projects.project_id', '=', $projectId)
            ->select('users.email', 'users.id', 'user_projects.role', 'project_invitations.email as invitedEmail','project_invitations.role as invitedRole')
            ->get();
```

Comment: You cannot get your desired result with joining the `users` table on `users.id` as in your desired result there is a null id where a user doesn't exist which would not join that column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use outer joins to get all records even if there is not a join for the record.

```
DB::table('user_projects')
            ->join('users', 'user_projects.user_id', '=', 'users.id', 'outer')
            ->join('project_invitations', 'project_invitations.project_id','=','user_projects.project_id', 'outer')
            ->where('user_projects.project_id', '=', $projectId)
            ->select('users.email', 'users.id', 'user_projects.role', 'project_invitations.email as invitedEmail','project_invitations.role as invitedRole')
            ->get();
```